# Why am I receiving 67 code from QOSStartTrackingClient method?

Tags: winapi, qos, getlasterror, sockaddr-in

I am receiving error code `67` from the code below, which means `ERROR_BAD_NET_NAME`.

Why is it happening? How can I fix it?

```
SOCKADDR address;
strcpy_s(address.sa_data, "8.8.8.8");
address.sa_family = AF_INET;

if (!QOSStartTrackingClient(QoSHandle, &address, 0))
    cout << GetLastError();
```

Comment: of course you initialize *SOCKADDR* wrong. by fact this must be *sockaddr_in*. it not accept string for ip. only in binary form as *ULONG S_addr*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you initialize [`SOCKADDR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740496(v=vs.85).aspx) wrong :

`strcpy_s(address.sa_data, "8.8.8.8");` - this is mistake.

really [`SOCKADDR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740496(v=vs.85).aspx) is only place holder

> Winsock functions using sockaddr are not strictly interpreted to be
>   pointers to a sockaddr structure. The structure is interpreted
>   differently in the context of different address families. The only
>   requirements are that the first u_short is the address family and the
>   total size of the memory buffer in bytes is namelen.

and from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/44a349sc.aspx)

> To actually fill in values for each part of an address, you use the
>   *SOCKADDR_IN* data structure, which is specifically for this address
>   format. The *SOCKADDR* and the *SOCKADDR_IN* data structures are the same
>   size. You simply cast to switch between the two structure types.

in your case you need use [`SOCKADDR_IN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx63b042.aspx)

```
    SOCKADDR_IN sa = { AF_INET };
    sa.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("8.8.8.8");
    if (!QOSStartTrackingClient(QoSHandle, (SOCKADDR*)&sa, 0))
        cout << GetLastError();
```

Comment: it looks like inet_addr is deprecated.

Comment: I used inet_pton(AF_INET, "8.8.8.8", &sa.sin_addr); instead but I still receive 67

Comment: @MatinLotfaliee but `SOCKADDR_IN sa = { AF_INET };` you execute before `inet_pton(AF_INET, "8.8.8.8", &sa.sin_addr);` ?

Comment: Yes. I execute it before inet_pton